# SpriteKit change sprite based on angle of Joystick

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, joystick

I have created a virtual joystick in my SpriteKit game with this code. all of my other nodes (like the map the player plays in and the scene setup etc.) are child nodes of the SKNode, worldNode, except for my joystick and player. So moving the worldNode moves the character around in the scene while keeping the camera centered on the character.

```
DPad = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dpad")
DPad.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
DPad.position = CGPoint(x: -270, y: -100)

DPad.zRotation = -1.0

thumbNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "joystick")
thumbNode.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
thumbNode.position = CGPoint(x: DPad.position.x, y: DPad.position.y)

self.addChild(DPad)
self.addChild(thumbNode)


//TOUCHES METHOD 

for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if isTracking == true {

            let v = CGVector(dx: location.x - DPad.position.x, dy: location.y - DPad.position.y)
            let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx)
            let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / Double.pi)

            let Length:CGFloat = DPad.frame.size.height / 2 - 20
            let xDist: CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.57079633) * Length
            let yDist: CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.57079633) * Length

            xJoystickDelta = location.x - DPad.position.x
            yJoystickDelta = location.y - DPad.position.y

            thumbNode.position = CGPoint(x: DPad.position.x - xDist, y: DPad.position.y + yDist)



            if DPad.contains(location) {
                thumbNode.position = location
            }else {
                thumbNode.position = CGPoint(x: DPad.position.x - xDist, y: DPad.position.y + yDist)
            }

        }
    }

//UPDATE METHOD 

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
    let xScale = CGFloat(0.06) //adjust to your preference
    let yScale = CGFloat(0.06) //adjust to your preference

    //xJoystickDelta and yJoystickDelta are CGFloats declared at the top of my scene
    let xAdd = xScale * self.xJoystickDelta
    let yAdd = yScale * self.yJoystickDelta

    worldNode.position.x -= xAdd
    worldNode.position.y -= yAdd

}
```

My Joystick is not tracking like I wanted it to, tracking in a cross method changing the sprite of my character based on where the thumb node is inside the four marked sections in the image below

[image: img1]

With my code above how can change the tracking of the cross so that the sprite of my character changes based on the position of the thumb Node inside the four sections of the X in the image below.

[image: img2]

(i apologize for the terrible image quality i whipped them up really fast to ask this question)

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but a dirty approach would just check if abs(y) > abs(x) to determine axis, then the sign of your axis to determine direction

Comment: i am trying to get my Joystick to properly track so that i can change my character sprite based on its position